# How to send javascript variables to django server using django?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, ajax

I just started learning web development,

### My objective: To display selected columns of a CSV file in server on the client page

So for some context on what I'm trying to do is,

- There are a few CSV files on my Django server.
- The client HTML page has a dropdown to select a file from a list of files and something like a filter for what columns to be displayed.
- I'm trying to get the values of the file and the filters using a button onclick method and send the values as an ajax request to the Django views.py.
- I will then use those variables to get the file, and the selected columns and use the render() function to render the HTML page dynamically

### My Questions:

- first of all, is what I'm doing the best way to handle my requirement? since I'm new to web-dev I don't know all the possible methods of achieving my requirement and I am doing it the only way I can think of.
- if what I'm doing is right, how do I send an ajax request to the server's views.py I can't seem to find the right code snippet/tutorial on how to send ajax request to views.py, all the tutorials I see are for databases.
- I made a Django app and in that app's views.py I'm trying to get the data from the client so I can open the requested CSV file from a static folder and render the right columns. am I supposed to handle this in views.py or should I do it in some other file?
- is my method dynamic? if not how should I do to make it dynamic?

### Code snippets:

- HTML page

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content%}

<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="container inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">CSV info</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner cover">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select class="custom-select">
                  <option disabled selected>Select Tweet file</option>
                  <option value="1">abc tweets</option>
                  <option value="2">def tweets</option>
                  <option value="3">hij tweets</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" name = "index" value = "true">Index</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2" name = "tid" value = "true">TweetID</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck3">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3" name = "tweet" value = "true">Tweets</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dispvalues()">Go</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
          <table class="table">
            {{header|safe}}
            <tbody>
              {{body|safe}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.table').hide();
    $('.custom-select').change(function () {
        selected_val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    });
  function dispvalues(){
    $('.custom-select').change(function () {
        selected_val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    });
    var index = $('#customCheck1').is(':checked');
    var tid = $('#customCheck2').is(':checked');
    var tweet = $('#customCheck3').is(':checked');
    var jsdata = [selected_val, index, tid, tweet];
    $('.table').show();
    var disp = selected_val + ' ' + index + ' ' + tid + ' ' + tweet;
    alert(disp);
  } 
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

- my views.py file

```
import os
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/tweets.csv'), 'r') as file:
        tweets = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
        table_header = '<thead><tr><th scope="col">index</th><th scope="col">tweetID</th><th scope="col">tweet</th></tr></thead>'
        table_body = format_csv_to_table(tweets)
    return render(request, "home.html",{"header": table_header, "body": table_body})

def format_csv_to_table(tweets):
    returnstr = ""
    for entry in tweets:
        row = '<tr><th scope="row">'+ entry[0] + '</th><td>' + entry[1] + '</td><td>' + entry[2] + '</td></tr>'
        returnstr += row
    return returnstr
```

- sample csv file

```
1, #2413, "slur1, slur2, slur3 abcsd sjkdy iyothfjsd aosudn"
2, #2414, "slur2 siod ushdj oiuiog ushydu gioufigo sidjio!!!"
3, #2415, "#slur4 skhdui sydghuy gofug uihdf sdki"
4, #2416, "slur5"
5, #2417, "slur1, slur1 sadhjkh usdhiu igfio"
```

[sample image of my current website #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmoHh.png)

[sample image of my current website #2 with dynamically displayed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXck0.png)

#### Note:

I have managed to learn how to render dynamically using render() the only thing I'm struggling with is getting the user data using ajax

Comment: Interact using APIs

Comment: @RajYadav could you please give me a reference link? what API should I use?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
async function sendData(data){
  let response = await fetch('<api_url>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  if(response.status === 200){
      let content = await response.json();
      console.log(content);
      //update your UI based on the response
  }else{
      let error=await response.text();
      console.log(`failed: ${error}`);
  }          
}
```

Call it,

```
sendData({data1: some_value,data2:some_other_value});
```

In your django API view,

```
def save_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         data = json.loads(request.body.decode("UTF-8"))
         data1 = data.get("data1", None) #receive data 1
         data2 = data.get("data2", None) #receive data 2

         #implement your logic here

    return HttpResponse("Method not allowed!", status=405)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are handling the data in the correct way. You could use the way suggested by @RajYadav in the above answer.
If you are using jQuery, you could do something like this :

```
`$.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            mode:'same-origin',
            type: "POST",
            url: yoururl,
            cache : false,
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response);

            },
            failure: function(xhr){
                console.log("failure");
                console.log(xhr);
            },
        });`
```